# How to avoiding UIButton's disable status with grayer effect on backgroundImage?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a Custom type UIButton, with different status:

```
button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "login_btn_normal"), for: .normal)
button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "login_btn_active"), for: .highlighted)
button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "login_btn_disable"), for: .disabled)
```

I have my disable effect in my image named "login_btn_disable", so I don't need the grayer effect automatically. what should I do?

this is my disable image
[image: this is my disable image]

but I got a effect like this when button is disabled
[image: but I got a effect like this when button is disabled]

Here is my sample: [UIButtonBackgroundImageT](https://github.com/huangxinyu1213/UIButtonBackgroundImageT)

Comment: why don't you set enable property for button

Comment: Of course I did, when the button was disabled, it has a gray effect unexpectedly.

Comment: Could you pls attach screen shot for enable and disable state ?

Comment: don't set enable property use  setUserInteractionEnabled Property or try to replace image instead of background

Comment: I have to change the backgroundImage when button' status was changed

Comment: For me it's working with your code, How you're disabling a button, pls show your code.

Comment: @Imad, just set isEnabled to false or true.

Comment: Have you tried to use setUserInteractionEnabled

Comment: That won't change the diffenent backgroundImage automatically when button change to nomal, disabled or highlighted.

Comment: @huangxinyu I tried sample, it shows correctly, doesn't show any disabled effect instead it shows my disabled image [see here](http://imgur.com/a/DBbwB)

Comment: @Imad, I don't know why, here is my sample.[UIButtonBackgroundImageT](https://github.com/huangxinyu1213/UIButtonBackgroundImageT)

Comment: @huangxinyu check my answer, you made a mistake with image name.

Comment: @Imad, OMG, it's really stupid mistake, I will kill my UED.

Comment: @huangxinyu This post should be deleted as it is no longer a programming question. Other users might distract and waste the time by refering it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through your code, you made a mistake with this line:

```
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "login_ben_disable"), for: .disabled)
```

OR 
Change the image name to `login_btn_disable` from `login_ben_disable`.

Comment: This question is my shame.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the button type as CustomType instand of SystemType.

Comment: This is custom type, and when set it to system, it's same.

Comment: Try to set the "adjustsImageWhenDisabled" NO.

Comment: I did, but the button won't change the backgroundImage when change to disEnabled from enabled.